# Calculate sum in script in ABBYY Flexicapture

Tags: abbyy

I would like to perform the function of a Calculate Sum rule with a Script rule in ABBYY Flexicapture, because I want to only perform the calculation based on evaluation of an if statement.

I have tried the following in a C# script rule:

```
IFields AllTaxes = Context.Field("cu_location_taxes").Rows;
```

which gives me the error "Field is not a table."

I have also tried

```
IFields AllTaxes = Context.Field("cu_location_taxes").Children;
```

which gives me the error "Cannot access fields not specified in rule settings." Even though I have added the repeating group cu_location_taxes to the c# script rule.

Once I am able to get them in some kind of array or list or IFields variable, I would like to sum the children values in some way. I am open to doing this with JScript or C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reasons of the errors you are facing can be found in ABBYY FlexiCapture Help.
In the description of IField class you can find the following descriptions of properties:

**Rows** - A set of table rows. ***Unavailable for non-table fields.***
Well, it seems to be that "cu_location_taxes" is not a table. You said, it is a repeating group.

**Children** - Child items of the field (cells for tables). ***Unavailable in script rules***. 
But as I understand, you are exactly using script rules.

To achieve correct results try to use **Items** property exactly of the fields that you are summing.

For example, you have a repeating group that contains number fields **field_1** and **field_2**. And you want to calculate the sum of all **field_1** instances.
Then you can use the following code (JScript):

```
sum = 0
for (i = 0; i < this.Field("field_1").Items.Count; ++i)
{
    sum += this.Field("field_1").Items.Item(i).Value
}
```

Also do not forget to add the **field_1** in available fields of your rule settings.
Hope this will help.